# Query for Update data in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP & just learning it, I have already inserted data by save() but I don't have any idea to how to update or delete data from MySQL database. I have find so many things on that these are not understandable for me.. can anyone help me out...

My ordersController is-

```
    class OrdersController extends AppController
    {
var $name = 'Orders';
var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
//var $ords = array('id', 'order_no' );

     public function order()
    { 
      $this->set('orders', $this->Order->find('all')); 

    }

    public function add_order()
    { 
                if (!empty($this->data)) {

                if ($this->Order->save($this->data)) {

                $this->redirect('/');
                }

                }
         }


      public function edit()
     {
```

///// this is my page name in view, what to do here..????

```
       }
```

///my model Order is --

```
      App::uses('Model', 'Model');

     class Order extends AppModel 
      {
   var  $name = 'Order';

       }
```

// I have no idea what to do in edit.php in view ...

thanks in advance

Comment: Follow the tutorial [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#editing-posts)

Comment: i have already read that and tried so much but this is not helpful for me..

Comment: you need to follow the naming conventions also, like you are using  edit.php whereas it is `edit.ctp` according to cake standard. for more info check [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html)

Comment: It sounds like you're quite out of your depth, and an answer on this site isn't going to solve your problems. If you've worked through the blog tutorial (actually done it, not just read it), then the next thing I'd look at is buying a CakePHP text book and working through that.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an File edit.ctp in your view folder

same as your add.ctp

then create an edit function in your controller
 like

public function edit($id = null){
     }

Now, From your index.ctp give link to this edit.ctp
       like

```
 eg.
 <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), array('action' => 'edit', $order['Order']['Id'])); ?>
```

will solve your purpose.

hi Try this controller function

public function edit($id = null) {

```
    if (!$this->Order->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid order'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {          

                if ($this->Order->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your order has been Modified Sucessfully'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your order not been Modified Sucessfully.'));
        }
    } 

            else {
        $this->request->data = $this->Order->read(null, $id);
         }

}
```

Comment: you have mention here..
echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), array('action' => 'edit', $user['User']['Id']));

Comment: i think its not $user.. i have to use $order..

because i have table name 'orders' and two fields id and order_no.

Comment: I just gave an example you can change it accordingly with what variable you have declared

Comment: i have tried as you suggest me but its not editing data, it is inserting new row data to the database...working just like add.ctp

edit.ctp is here-
       <div class="index">

 <h2>Edit Order</h2>

 
        <?php

          echo $this->Form->create('Order', array('action' => 'add_order'));

         echo $this->Form->input('id');

         echo $this->Form->input('order_no');

         echo $this->Form->end('Submit');

          ?>

          }

Comment: I Think You Are Not Passing The id or your edit function() function is not getting the id

Comment: i have modified the answer check it

Comment: echo $this->Form->create('Order') ,just use for tag as mentioned

Comment: by adding your controller function the whole project showing this error-

An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Comment: try to modified it according to your variable it a tested working function.